# Replace fixed number of symbols in String

Tags: java

I have this number: `4200000000000000`
I would like to leave only the first 4 digits and last 3 digits:

```
42000......000
```

Everything else should be replaced by dots. How I can implement this with some smart algorithm?

Comment: Is the input a `String`? And I'm assuming you want to return a `String`?

Comment: Yes - I want String

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a `StringBuilder` and the [`substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) method:

```
public static String foo(long num) {
    String numToString = String.valueOf(num);
    return new StringBuilder()
              .append(numToString.substring(0 , 4))
              .append("....")
              .append(numToString.substring(numToString.length()-3, numToString.length()))
              .toString();
}
```

When inputted `4200000000000000` it outputs:

```
4200....000
```

Or if the input is already a `String`:

```
public static String foo(String str) {
    return new StringBuilder()
            .append(str.substring(0 , 4))
            .append("....")
            .append(str.substring(str.length()-3, str.length()))
            .toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse your number into a string and try this:

```
int last = 3;
int first = 4;
String number = '4200000000000000';
String start = number.substring(0,first-1);
String end = number.substring(number.length()-last,number.length()-1);
String dots = '';

for(int i = 0; i<number.length()-last-first;i++){
  dots = dots + '.';
}

String result = start + dots + end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this,

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(convert("4200000000000000", 4, 3));
    }

    static String convert(String number, int firstDigits, int lastDigits) {
        String first = number.substring(0, firstDigits);
        String middle = number.substring(firstDigits, number.length() - lastDigits).replaceAll("0", ".");
        String last = number.substring(number.length() - lastDigits, number.length());

        return first + middle + last;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert it to a char array, alter it, then convert it back into a string

```
    char[] charArray = originalNumber.toCharArray();

    for (int i; i < charArray.length; i++) {
        if (i <= 4 || i >= charArray.length - 3) {
        charArray[i] = ".";
        }
    }
    String outputString = new String(charArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will replace all chars from the 4th char up to the 4th from the end with '.':

```
    String start = "4200000000000000";
    System.out.println(start);

    String target = start;
    if (start.length() > 7) {
        target = new StringBuilder()
                .append(start.substring(0, 4))
                .append(new String(new char[start.length() - 7]).replaceAll(".", "."))
                .append(start.substring(start.length() - 3))
                .toString();
    }
    System.out.println(target);
```

will print

```
4200000000000000
4200.........000
```

Answer (score 0):

Using substring method of the String class :

```
String str = "4200000000000000";
String res = str.substring(0,4)+ str.substring(4,str.length()-3).replaceAll(".", ".") + str.substring(str.length()-3);
```

If you are using Apache commons library, you can use repeat method to create masking string of specified length and the overlay method of StringUtils class to overlay part of the String :

```
String str = "4200000000000000";
String mask= StringUtils.repeat('.', str.length()-7);        
String res = StringUtils.overlay(str, mask, 4, str.length()-3);
```